# When the first stage is array, How to handle with go-simplejson

Tags: go

JSON struct like below:

```json
[
  {
    "sha": "eb08dc1940e073a5c40d8b53a5fd58760fde8f27",
    "node_id": "C_kwDOHb9FrtoAKGViMDhkYzE5NDBlMDczYTVjNDBkOGI1M2E1ZmQ1ODc2MGZkZThmMjc",
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        "name": "xxxx"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "xxxxx"
      },
      "message": "update DownLoad_Stitch_ACM.py",
      "tree": {
        "sha": "a30aab98319846f0e86da4a39ec05786e04c0a4f",
        "url": "xxxxx"
      },
      "url": "xxxxx",
      "comment_count": 0,
      "verification": {
        "verified": false,
        "reason": "unsigned",
        "signature": null,
        "payload": null
      }
    },
    "url": "xxxxx",
    "html_url": "xxxxx",
    "comments_url": "xxxxx",
    "author": {
      "login": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "node_id": "U_kgDOBkuicQ",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/105620081?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "committer": {
      "login": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    "parents": [
      {
        "sha": "cf867ec9dc4b904c466d9ad4b9338616d1213a06",
        "url": "xxxxx",
        "html_url": "xxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to get the location 0's data.

```golang
content, _ := simplejson.NewJson(body)
arr, _ := content.Array()  // Here can get the all data, It's []interface{} type.
```

I cannot get the next data with `arr[0]["sha"]`. How to handle it?

Comment: Got. Thanks a lot for you who spent a long time to handle this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to the compiler that `arr` is an array of `map[string]interface{}` at compile time, as `arr[0]` is of type `interface{}`. This basically means that the compiler knows nothing about this type, which is why you can't do a map lookup operation here.

You can add a type assertion to make sure you can use it as a map like this:

```
asMap := arr[0].(map[string]interface{})
fmt.Println(asMap["sha"])
```

To get the SHA as string, you can again add a type assertion behind it as well:

```
asString := asMap["sha"].(string)
```

This is also shown in [this working example](https://goplay.space/#JZrcHWBqXo0). The downside of this is that your program will panic in case the given data is not of the specified type. You could instead use a type assertion with a check if it worked (`asString, ok := ...`), but it gets cumbersome with more complex data.

---

This does work, but isn't really nice. I would recommend using a [tool like this](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to generate Go structs and then use them in a type-safe way. First define a struct with all the info you need:

```
type ArrayElement struct {
    Sha string `json:"sha"`
    // Add more fields if you need them
}
```

Then you can just use the standard-library `json` package to unmarshal your data:

```
// This should have the same structure as the data you want to parse
var result []ArrayElement

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &result)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(result[0].Sha)
```

[Here](https://goplay.space/#LVsXXpQlRTb) is an example for that -- this is a more Go-like approach for converting JSON data.

Comment: Type assertion can handle this ,  Thanks a lot.arr, _ := content.Array()
 asMap := arr[0].(map[string]interface{})

 fmt.Println(asMap["sha"])
 fmt.Println(asMap["node_id"])      Output:  eb08dc1940e073a5c40d8b53a5fd58760fde8f27
C_kwDOHb9FrtoAKGViMDhkYzE5NDBlMDczYTVjNDBkOGI1M2E1ZmQ1ODc2MGZkZThmMjc

Answer (score 0):

Your json data is wrong formatted. First of all, remove `,` after `"id": "xxxxx",` line:

```
    ...
    "id": "xxxxx"
    ...
```

You should check errors after `NewJson` to prevent find out if there is a problem:

```
    content, err := simplejson.NewJson(body)
    if err != nil {
        // log err
    }
```

For getting `sha` from first index, you simply can use simplejson built-in methods:

```
shaVal := content.GetIndex(0).Get("sha").String()
```

Comment: For data security,  I modified some data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the desired value.

This worked for me.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyData []struct {
    Sha    string `json:"sha"`
    NodeID string `json:"node_id"`
    Commit struct {
        Author struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"author"`
        Committer struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"committer"`
        Message string `json:"message"`
        Tree    struct {
            Sha string `json:"sha"`
            URL string `json:"url"`
        } `json:"tree"`
        URL          string `json:"url"`
        CommentCount int    `json:"comment_count"`
        Verification struct {
            Verified  bool        `json:"verified"`
            Reason    string      `json:"reason"`
            Signature interface{} `json:"signature"`
            Payload   interface{} `json:"payload"`
        } `json:"verification"`
    } `json:"commit"`
    URL         string `json:"url"`
    HTMLURL     string `json:"html_url"`
    CommentsURL string `json:"comments_url"`
    Author      struct {
        Login      string `json:"login"`
        ID         string `json:"id"`
        NodeID     string `json:"node_id"`
        AvatarURL  string `json:"avatar_url"`
        GravatarID string `json:"gravatar_id"`
        Type       string `json:"type"`
        SiteAdmin  bool   `json:"site_admin"`
    } `json:"author"`
    Committer struct {
        Login string `json:"login"`
        ID    string `json:"id"`
    } `json:"committer"`
    Parents []struct {
        Sha     string `json:"sha"`
        URL     string `json:"url"`
        HTMLURL string `json:"html_url"`
    } `json:"parents"`
}

func main() {

    my_json_data := `[
  {
    "sha": "eb08dc1940e073a5c40d8b53a5fd58760fde8f27",
    "node_id": "C_kwDOHb9FrtoAKGViMDhkYzE5NDBlMDczYTVjNDBkOGI1M2E1ZmQ1ODc2MGZkZThmMjc",
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        "name": "xxxx"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "xxxxx"
      },
      "message": "update DownLoad_Stitch_ACM.py",
      "tree": {
        "sha": "a30aab98319846f0e86da4a39ec05786e04c0a4f",
        "url": "xxxxx"
      },
      "url": "xxxxx",
      "comment_count": 0,
      "verification": {
        "verified": false,
        "reason": "unsigned",
        "signature": null,
        "payload": null
      }
    },
    "url": "xxxxx",
    "html_url": "xxxxx",
    "comments_url": "xxxxx",
    "author": {
      "login": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "node_id": "U_kgDOBkuicQ",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/105620081?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "committer": {
      "login": "xxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxx"
    },
    "parents": [
      {
        "sha": "cf867ec9dc4b904c466d9ad4b9338616d1213a06",
        "url": "xxxxx",
        "html_url": "xxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }]`

    var data MyData
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(my_json_data), &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("data --> sha: ", data[0].Sha)
}
```